# Using Saved Spark Model to Evaluate New Data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I've been successful in building a transforming my data into a LibSVM file, and training a decision tree model on it in Spark's MLlib package. I used the Scala code in [the 1.6.2 documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/mllib-decision-tree.html#regression), changing only the filenames:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.DecisionTreeModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils

// Load and parse the data file.
val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")
// Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
val (trainingData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))

// Train a DecisionTree model.
//  Empty categoricalFeaturesInfo indicates all features are continuous.
val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()
val impurity = "variance"
val maxDepth = 5
val maxBins = 32

val model = DecisionTree.trainRegressor(trainingData, categoricalFeaturesInfo, impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)

// Evaluate model on test instances and compute test error
val labelsAndPredictions = testData.map { point =>
  val prediction = model.predict(point.features)
  (point.label, prediction)
}
val testMSE = labelsAndPredictions.map{ case (v, p) => math.pow(v - p, 2) }.mean()
println("Test Mean Squared Error = " + testMSE)
println("Learned regression tree model:\n" + model.toDebugString)

// Save and load model
model.save(sc, "target/tmp/myDecisionTreeRegressionModel")
val sameModel = DecisionTreeModel.load(sc, "target/tmp/myDecisionTreeRegressionModel")
```

The code correctly displays the model's MSE and learned tree model. However, I'm stuck in figuring out how to take the `sameModel` and use it to evaluate new data. Like, if the LibSVM file that I used to train the model looks like this:

```
0 1:1.0 2:0.0 3:0.0 4:0.0 5:0.0 6:0.0 7:0.0 8:0.0 9:0.0 10:0.0 11:0.0 12:0 13:0 14:0 15:9 16:19
0 1:1.0 2:0.0 3:0.0 4:0.0 5:0.0 6:0.0 7:0.0 8:0.0 9:0.0 10:0.0 11:0.0 12:1 13:0 14:0 15:9 16:12
0 1:1.0 2:0.0 3:0.0 4:0.0 5:0.0 6:0.0 7:0.0 8:0.0 9:0.0 10:0.0 11:0.0 12:0 13:0 14:0 15:6 16:7
```

How do I feed the trained model something like this, and have it predict the label?

```
1:1.0 2:0.0 3:0.0 4:0.0 5:0.0 6:0.0 7:0.0 8:0.0 9:0.0 10:0.0 11:0.0 12:0 13:0 14:0 15:9 16:19
1:1.0 2:0.0 3:0.0 4:0.0 5:0.0 6:0.0 7:0.0 8:0.0 9:0.0 10:0.0 11:0.0 12:1 13:0 14:0 15:9 16:12
1:1.0 2:0.0 3:0.0 4:0.0 5:0.0 6:0.0 7:0.0 8:0.0 9:0.0 10:0.0 11:0.0 12:0 13:0 14:0 15:6 16:7
```

**EDIT (8/31/2017 3:56 PM, Eastern)**

Per the below suggestions, I'm trying the predict function, but it doesn't look like the code is quite right:

```
val new_data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "hdfs://.../new_data/*")

val labelsAndPredictions = new_data.map { point =>
  val prediction = sameModel.predict(point.features)
  (point.label, prediction)
}

labelsAndPredictions.take(10)
```

If I run this with a LibSVM file containing '1' values as the label (I'm testing with ten new rows in the file), then they all come back as '1.0' in the `labelsAndPredictions.take(10)` command. If I give it a '0' value, then they all come back as '0.0', so it doesn't seem like anything's being predicted properly.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution to the above problem of predicting a label?

Answer (score 1):

1. load raw data (as you did above, a similar LibSVM file)
2. provide information about categorical features
3. for each point in above data make predictions by calling:  savedModel.predict(point.features)

Comment: if I just remove the label from the LibSVM file ("1:1.0 2:0.0..."), Spark doesn't like this. It fails to execute that new line of code, calling out the `java.lang.NumberFormat Exception: For input string: "1:1.0"` error. What do you put in that place?

Comment: I did not understand the issue you are facing in the above 'comment'. 
As per your Edit above, one follow-up: Are you sure, you are looking at the predictions that come back? (Your code does seem to be right)

Comment: You can see where the `take()` is pulling from in the code in the edit made yesterday. The label values show there seem to match whatever label values are in my input `"hdfs://.../new_data/*"` file.

Answer (score 0):

The load method should return a model.  Then call `predict` with either a RDD[Vector] or a single Vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can load ML model from the disk via `Pipeline`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml._
val pipeline = Pipeline.read.load("sample-pipeline")

scala> val stageCount = pipeline.getStages.size
stageCount: Int = 0

val pipelineModel = PipelineModel.read.load("sample-model")

scala> pipelineModel.stages
```

After obtaining `pipeline` use can make evaluation on the dataset:

```
val model = pipeline.fit(dataset)
val predictions = model.transform(dataset)
```

And you must use proper `Evaluator` e.g. `RegressionEvaluator`.
Evaluator works on datasets with predictions:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.RegressionEvaluator
val regEval = new RegressionEvaluator
println(regEval.explainParams)
regEval.evaluate(predictions)
```

**UPD** If you have deal with `hdfs` you can easily load/save model:

One way to save a model to HDFS is as following:

```
// persist model to HDFS
sc.parallelize(Seq(model), 1).saveAsObjectFile("hdfs:///user/root/sample-model")
```

Saved model can then be loaded as:

```
val linRegModel = sc.objectFile[LinearRegressionModel]("hdfs:///user/root/sample-model").first()
linRegModel.predict(Vectors.dense(11.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2200.0))
```

or like in example above, but instead local file `hdfs`:

```
PipelineModel.read.load("hdfs:///user/root/sample-model")
```

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks for sharing! One question, none of the existing files that I have on HDFS are suitable to replace the "sample-pipeline" section in line two of your code. What are you loading there?

Comment: Sorry, I'm just now getting back to this. Using the file name from the `model.save()` command in my original code, all three of the methods you suggest result in errors when run through the REPL. Using `PipelineModel.read.load()` gives error: `org.json42.package$MappingException: Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String`. The `objectFile[]()` method results in error: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist`. I'm able to load the saved model with `DecisionTreeModel.load()`, but can't seem to USE it once it's loaded.

Comment: @EB you can seamlessly migrate it to Python, just replace imports and take into account dynamic typing in Python (just remove `val` everywhere)

Answer (score 0):

Ship the file with hdfs to a directory where all nodes can see it in the cluster. In your code load it and predict.